# What are the sources of energy that alcohol provides?

Tags: food

Milk contains sugar and proteins which give energy. What compounds in alcoholic beverages *(edited)* give energy? Are they more likely to turn into fat (as in beer belly) than blood glucose?

Comment: alcohol is not a mixture, it is one defined molecule, ethanol (assuming the colloquial definition of alcohol, it can also mean a class of molecules).

Comment: @MadScientist My bad, I meant alcoholic beverages like beer, wine, rum and whiskey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ethanol is converted into [AcKoA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetyl-CoA), which can be "burned" in the [Krebs cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citric_acid_cycle) or can be used to [build fatty acids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatty_acid_synthesis).

[image: ethanol - AcKoA conversion]

By chronic alcohol consumption there is another pathway involving [MEOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsomal_ethanol_oxidizing_system) which converts ethanol to AcKoA as well.

> Are they more likely to turn into fat (as in beer belly) than blood
>   glucose?

It won't turn into glucose, just into fat.

*Note:*

It is suspected that in extreme cases, like low glucose diets and starvation there is an **AcKoA -> glucose** pathway.

- 2011 - [In Silico Evidence for Gluconeogenesis from Fatty Acids in Humans](http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pcbi.1002116)

So in theory it is possible to convert ethanol to glucose, but there is not enough evidence of that yet. Normally this conversion (if it exists) does not happen, or it has a very low rate...

> What compounds in alcoholic beverages (edited) give energy?

Mostly ethanol and sugar. E.g. sweet wine contains a lot of sugar, not just ethanol...

Comment: Is AcKoA more likely to be deposited as under-skin fat, like the myth of beer makes your belly especially fatter? Sorry I was vague about "turn into fat"

Comment: Liver does not produce fat normally, it just mediates the fat transport after eating by creating lipoproteins. I don't know the details of the process, but alcohol can cause fatty liver, so I think the fat is more likely deposited in the liver and in visceral fat depos, than by eating fatty foods. So the myth can be true, but you need more googling to find evidence. http://scholar.google.com

Answer (score 1):

### Regarding energy:

Going off the assumption that you are using 'alcohol' in the sense of 'alcoholic beverage', it *really* depends on what kind of beverage we're talking about, but all that information is on the label of the bottle, can or box.

As for ethanol itself, some energy is freed by the metabolising of ethanol into ethanal and further into ethanoic acid, before finally being decomposed to carbon dioxide and water.

Finally, energy is energy: The source of the energy doesn't *really* affect where the energy ends up, that depends mostly on external factors.

---

### Regarding beer:

Ethanol gives roughly 7 kcal/g, compared to carbohydrates which give roughly 4 kcal/g.

100 ml of beer contains (about) 4 grams of ethanol, beyond which the carbohydrate content varies according to the beer in question, but usually hovers around 3 g.

At a rough estimate the caloric contribution from ethanol is about 0.28 kcal/ml, and carbohydrates about 0.12 kcal/ml. When accounting for the traces of proteins, this gives roughly 0.4 kcal/ml, roughly the same as your common or garden variety soda.

Comment: So what compound provides most of the energy in, say a beer?

Comment: @aitchnyu: Updating answer with this information now.

Comment: Right, ethanol can be oxidized.

Comment: Carbohydrates, as in leftover fruit sugars from the source?

Comment: @aitchnyu: In addition to additives and adulterants, yes.